# How do i Prevent CKEditor convert hexadecimal character to decimal character?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ckeditor

I'm working in CKEditor a few weeks ago.I face some issues now.

CKEditor automatically converts the hexadecimal character to decimal character.

This is the Hexa char I gave t
o the editor.

```
&#x2013;
```

What CKEditor converts.

```
 &#38;
```

How do I prevent this conversion.

Please, anybody help me to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You may use [config.entities_additional](https://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-entities_additional) like:

```
config.entities_additional = '#x2013';
```

to tell CKEditor that this entity could be used inside the editor (so it won't get converted).

Comment: What if I want all the hexadecimal character list.They are thousand of them.#f1ames

Comment: The strange think is that you mentioned `&#x2013;` gets converted to `&#38;` which are two different characters. Are you sure that is the case and that it is CKEditor doing that?

How do you input the hex char and how do you check if it get converted (which methods do you sue to get data from editor)?

Comment: Please take a look at my previous comment. It will be easier to investigate if you provide some details (you can edit your question by adding some steps how to reproduce this case).

Comment: Ok,I will look at this the way you said.